# CSS stack multiple full width divs

Tags: html, css

I have this markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  width: 200%;
}

.block {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Basically all I want to do is, have 2 fullwidth divs floating next to each other, but when I put some content in them I get container centered and pieces of both divs showing, like this: http://prntscr.com/8lr4l6

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean two HALF width next to each other to make up FULL width?

Comment: Nope, I mean it like this:
#wrapper is 100% of the screen width with overflow: hidden,
#container is 200% wide and each block is 50% width of the #container, making them 100% of the screen (one of the blocks is meant to be off screen)

Comment: so you want one full block on the screen and one block off the screen. can i ask why you would like it like that (like how you want to access the block that is never shown)?

Comment: I want to use it for transition, like second div slides in from the right side

Answer (score 0):

There is **no need** to set the width of the wrapper and of the container. It is **always 100%**, if nothing else is set. Just set a width of 50% to every block and float them left.

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nq0kn886/)

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/338/

you can see the div to by commenting out `overflow: hidden`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block block1">
        This is content for div 1 This is content for div 1 This is content for div 1
    </div>
    <div class="block block2">
        This is content for div 2 This is content for div 2 This is content for div 2
    </div>
</div>


body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 200%;
    padding: 0px;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boy, am I a fool!? 
In my case answer was pretty simple. I had left autofocus attribute on my input which were on the off screen div, and of course it automatically scrolled to that div.

Thanks everyone for answers though. :)